# persisting array state to local storage

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, local-storage

I've built a simple Todo List app with React. The todo list tasks are held in an array on state. I want to be able to persist the same todo list array after refreshing the browser. To do so, I tried to implement local storage in my project. Setting the todo array to local storage. However, after inserting the following code, the app breaks and I get an error that says props.todos.map is not a function.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const todos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    this.setState({ 
      ...this.state.todos, 
      todos });
  }
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue with the local storage code? Here is the rest of the code for that component (App.js). I will include the code for the other components below (just in case that helps get me an answer) but I'm pretty sure the problem is in the App.js somewhere in the code snippet I posted above. When I comment that snippet out, the app goes back to working how it was before, but obviously, I am still unable to persist state.

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          task: "learn how to fly drone",
          id: 1,
          completed: false
        }, 
        {
          task: "learn React class components",
          id: 2,
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "practice editing videos",
          id: 3,
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: "read Ten Years A Nomad",
          id: 4,
          completed: false
        }
    ],
      todo: ''
    }
  }

  inputChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }

  addTask = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTask = {
      task: this.state.todo,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false
    };
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, newTask],
      todo: ''
    })
    const { todos } = this.state;
    localStorage.setItem("todos", todos);
  }

  toggleComplete = itemId => {
    const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === itemId) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo
    });
    this.setState({todos, todo: ''})
  }

  clearCompleted = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter(item => !item.completed);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      todos
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const todos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    this.setState({ 
      ...this.state.todos, 
      todos });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="header">
          <h2 className="title">Welcome to your Todo App!</h2>
          <TodoForm todos={this.state.todos} value={this.state.todo} inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler} addTask={this.addTask} clearCompleted={this.clearCompleted}/>
        </div>
        <TodoList 
          todos={this.state.todos} 
          toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js:

```
const TodoList = props => {
    return (
        <ul className="todo-list">
            {props.todos.map((todo, id) => (
                    <Todo 
                        todo={todo} 
                        key={id} 
                        toggleComplete={props.toggleComplete} 
                    />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default TodoList;
```

Todo.js:

```
const Todo = props => {
    return (
            <li 
                className={props.todo.completed ? "completed-todos" : "todos"}
                style={{textDecoration: props.todo.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}
                key={props.todo.id}
                onClick={() => {
                    props.toggleComplete(props.todo.id)
                }}
            >
                {props.todo.task}
            </li>
    )
}

export default Todo;
```

TodoForm.js:

```
const TodoForm = props => {
    return (
        <form className="add-form">
            <input 
                className="add-input"
                name="todo" 
                value={props.value} 
                type="text" 
                onChange={props.inputChangeHandler} 
                placeholder="Enter new task" />
            <button className="add-button" onClick={props.addTask}>Add Todo</button>
            <button className="clear-button" onClick={props.clearCompleted}>Clear Completed</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Comment: local storage keys and the values are *always strings*. you will have to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert to array

Comment: I changed the addTask onClick function to include JSON.stringify and the componentDidMount part to include JSON.parse. Now it's throwing a different error: a cross-origin error. React doesn't have access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage stores key-value pairs. So to store a javascript object you need to serialize it with JSON.stringify(**object => String**) and to retrieve item from localStorage you need to convert to an object again with JSON.parse(**String =>object**)

So change `addTask`  and `componentDidMount` like below:

```
  addTask = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTask = {
      task: this.state.todo,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false
    };
    this.setState(
      {
        todos: [...this.state.todos, newTask],
        todo: ""
      },
      () => {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.state.todos));
      }
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const todos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    if (todos) this.setState({ todos: JSON.parse(todos) });
  }
```

Here is the temporary [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-ke5mh)  containing the fixed version

Comment: I did exactly what you (I think) did and I'm getting a cross-origin error now. I went over your codesandbox like four or five times. For some reason, my componentDidMount call is breaking the code.

Comment: I think it's because you already had a todos item in local storage from the past.go and delete the old one. if you have sandbox put the link here

Comment: That was exactly it. Cleared the browser history and cookies and whatnot and issue is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, instead of clear the browser history, you can just go to the developer tools by pressing F12 , then go to the Application tab. In the Storage section expand Local Storage. After that, you'll see all your browser's local storage there.